# WebRTC with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webrtc, video-conferencing

Please can someone give me a link to a good tutorial on building a WebRTC video conferencing application with ASP.NET Mvc.

I'm trying to build an ASP.Net Mvc application which has a feature of video conferencing and wants to do it using WebRTC. If there is a better way to build it other than WebRTC please do tell.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Comment: i also found https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/